# Restore from trash not working?

Tags: system

I tried to restore some files from trash but it just closes and the files aren't restored, they're still in the trash. The empty trash function works, however.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug: [restore from trash fails](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1622053)

Was confirmed and as i see fixed by Jeremy Wootten.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile Jeremy's branch and this fixes the bug for me.

Please read his comment...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1622053/comments/10

Maybe someone else can test this and give an answer to the [**bug report**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1622053).

Comment: Note: Don't attempt to apply patches on your own unless you know what you are doing and need this fix right away. For the majority of the users, it's best to wait until the devs apply the patch and ship it with the usual updates.